# No such file or directory error with Nginx proxy pass

Tags: nginx, node.js

I have configured nginx to pass nodejs server (8081) port to external url https://example.com/myapp

MyApp = nodejs server api and its working fine

I have another admin control interface for it and the complete url is https://example.com/myapp/admin

Error comming while i am trying to login into the admin interface. with http url its working fine.

Eroor Log:

```
  2016/03/08 11:20:28 [error] 25762#0: *16 open() "/usr/share/nginx/html/example.com/apis/users/admin/login/email" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 202.164.23.112, server: example.com, request: "POST /apis/users/admin/login/email HTTP/1.1", host: "example.com", referrer: "https://example.com/myapp/admin"
```

Where the apis/users/admin/login/email are all these pages not directories.

Nginx Server Configurations:   */etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default*

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name localhost;
    listen 443;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;
   ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;

location /myapp/ {
    proxy_pass https://0.0.0.0:8081;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    rewrite ^/myapp/(.*) /$1 break;
```

}

Please advise and thanks in advance:

Comment: Request to `/apis/` doesn't match your `location`. Show full config

Comment: You mean should i share complete Nginx default file full configuration ?

Comment: Full config for the server block in question

Comment: Updated in the question please see above.

Comment: You have POST to `/api/user/...`, but your config has no location that matches it. So nginx tries to serve static file and could not find it